# Block approving edit/review queue before reading all the text (scrolling page to the end)

Tags: feature-request, review

I request disable approving/accepting feature in all the review queues, if the user didn't read the page to the end (I mean scrolled to the end).

**Why?**

Some users, when they see review queue look only at the beginng (I mean the part of the post, which is located on the screen; part showed without scrolling down the page) of the edited/written post. That's bad. Post at the beginning could be good, at the bottom of it the vandalism/spam/inappropiate content could be located....

Comment: what if it's vandalism at the start? Should I have to scroll to the end before rejecting anyways?

Comment: @Jan I think he means block approvals only and still allow rejects

Comment: @JanDvorak I told about approve button

Comment: in which case - go ahead. Also, some rejection reasons (2minor) might make sense disabling.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Yes, but I think reviewer also wants as the best as possible for SO. I don't tell about roboreviewers... Sometimes we simply forget about scrolling the page, etc.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Ok, so we're talking about newbie reviewers. Sometimes also advanced users simply forget about scrolling the page...

Comment: what if the comment for the edit is 'Cleaned up grammar in title', and you see the title changes? after all, if the editor indicated that all the changes were at the top of the question/answer, why should i have to scroll to the bottom just to fulfill some bogus requirement? i see downside, and not a lot of upside...

Comment: @Corley, the point still stands that the user could have defaced the bottom half of that post

Comment: @OGHaza - good point, didn't think about intentional deception. i'll keep that in mind.